# Accessing Parent Scope inside UI carousel

Tags: angularjs

I am using UI Carousel, but facing difficulty in accessing parent scope inside it.
Below is the demo code for the same.

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="menuCard">
       <div class="food-item-section" ng-repeat="type in foodTypes">
           <p class="food-section-header">
                {{type.toUpperCase()}}
           </p>
           <ui-carousel 
                slides="slideMenu[type.toUpperCase()]"
                slides-to-show="3"
                slides-to-scroll="1"
                initial-slide="1"
                autoplay="false",
                dots = "true"
                >
          <carousel-item>
            <div class="item-box">
               <img src="../images/FoodItems/{{item.itemName}}.jpg" class="img img-thumbnail img-responsive" />
                <h4 class="text-center">{{item.itemName}}</h4>
                 <h3 class="text-center">₹ {{item.itemPrice }}</h3>
                 <div class="text-center">
                 <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-5">
                 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-menu btn-success" ng-click="increaseQuantity(item)">+</button>
```

The issue is the function increaseQuantity is not being called. It is defined in controller like this :

```
$scope.increaseQuantity = function(item) {
  console.log(item);
};
```

Need help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look [here](https://github.com/mihnsen/ui-carousel/issues/31) you can try the following in your `items` array:

```
items.map((item) { 
    item.callback = () => { 
        console.log(item); 
    } 
    return item;
});
```

And then:

```
ng-click="item.callback()"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but $parent.increaseQuantity(item) is not causing any change in behaviour.

Comment: After a little search, updated my answer. If it doesn't work for you, please create a fiddle demonstrating the behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks it works. Atleast I am now able to catch the event. Will work on my code and see if the functionality can be achieved. Thanks a lot again.